# how to get pages or frames inside CoreWindow in UWP app

Tags: uwp, frame, uwp-xaml, multi-window

I am working on a UWP library , in which I would like get all frames or pages inside a CoreWindow or CoreApplicationView.

In multi window app,

I can get all available views by this code `CoreApplication.Views` . `Views` is a collection of `CoreApplicationView` .

From this all I want is to get is frames and pages loaded inside this each views.

Can anybody help me in this.

Thanks

Noorul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CoreWindow` or `CoreApplicationView` does not provide APIs to directly access internal Xaml elements.

If you want to access the Xaml element in the window, you need to get the `Window` object. Currently, UWP application can only get the active window

If you need to get the Xaml elements in the current window, you need to use `Window.Current`:

```cs
public IEnumerable<Frame> GetFrames(Frame rootFrame = null)
{
    if (rootFrame == null)
        rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    if (rootFrame.Content is Page page)
    {
        var children = VisualTreeFindAll<Frame>(page);
        if (children.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var childFrame in children)
            {
                GetFrames(childFrame);
                yield return childFrame;
            }
        }
    }
}

public IList<T> VisualTreeFindAll<T>(DependencyObject element)
    where T : DependencyObject
{
    List<T> retValues = new List<T>();
    var childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element);
    for (var i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i);
        var type = child as T;
        if (type != null)
        {
            retValues.Add(type);
        }
        retValues.AddRange(VisualTreeFindAll<T>(child));
    }
    return retValues;
}
```

**Usage**

```cs
var frames = GetFrames();
```

Comment: Is it possible to get notified or any event to track , while new window is opened !? 
#MultiWindow #UWP

Comment: Not currently, but the operation of creating a new window should be done in accordance with the logic written in advance. You can maintain a window List and add corresponding items when creating a new window.